# How can I convert a string into a list and then back to a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I just want to know how can I convert a string of numbers per example:

```
numbers = "1,3,5,12,36,81"
```

in a list, square all the numbers and then print it as a string.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `print (*[int(i)**2 for i in numbers.split(',')])` is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes. That would've done it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To go from a `string` to a `list`, you split it, it there is a pattern, here the comma. Then square all with a list-comprehension, then join them to go bach to a `string`

```
numbers = "1,3,5,12,36,81"
values = numbers.split(',')                     # ['1', '3', '5', '12', '36', '81']
values = [int(val) ** 2 for val in values]      # [1, 9, 25, 144, 1296, 6561]
numbers = ",".join(str(val) for val in values)  # 1,9,25,144,1296,6561
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have only integars

```
",".join(map(str,[int(i)*int(i) for i in numbers.split(',')]))


   '1,9,25,144,1296,6561'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a string at the end:

```
numbers = "1,3,5,12,36,81"
results = ','.join( [ str(int(x)**2) for x in numbers.split(",")] )
print (results)
```

Output is:

```
1,9,25,144,1296,6561
```

I would recommend keeping the numbers in a list if you can.

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
my_list = numbers.split(',')
square_roots = ','.join([math.sqrt(int(x)) for x in my_list])
print(square_roots)
```

Comment: Creating a lambda at each iteration to apply it directly so  counterintuitive, a bad practice, bad efficient

Comment: You're right, thanks, fixed it.

Comment: @HosseinHeydari OP asks for squares not square roots.

Comment: The community [encourages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712) adding explanations alongside code, rather than purely code-based answers. As explained [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837): "While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value."